# Embed a (saved) Leaflet map in an Ioslides presentation

Tags: leaflet, r

I'm building some fairly complex maps with the `leaflet` package and I'd like to embed them in an rmarkdown document (specifically an `ioslides_presentation` .Rmd file).

Right now the code for the maps is in an .R script and it is subject to change as I tinker around with map aesthetics. I know I can cut and paste each map's code into the .Rmd presentation doc, but I want to avoid have to manually update the .Rmd file every time a change is made. I figure that if I can save the `leaflet` output and embed it in the presentation that will be much smoother.

I know that `htmlwidgets::saveWidget` allows me to save `leaflet` maps. But how can I embed these outputs in the .Rmd presentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your map codes in a separate Rmd file, and include it in your main file.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yihui/knitr/master/inst/examples/child/knitr-main.Rmd

Answer (score 0):

I ended up hosting the output of `htmlwidget::saveWidget` on a [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/) project website. I embedded the `html` files in the ioslides presentation using an iframe, as demonstrated below:

```
<iframe  title="My Map" width="980" height="400" src="http://username.github.io/reponame/maps/my_map.html" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This approach has advantages and disadvantages for my workflow. I like that I do not have to create separate `.Rmd` files for the `leaflet` functions because I want to keep all of my analysis and visualization code together in one script. That said, hosting and embedding the `html` files means I have to add a `git push` to the `gh-pages` branch whenever I tweak the maps.

I decided to leave @bhaskar-karambelkar's solution marked correct because it is more straightforward than my own.